# How to use LZ4 compression functions in kernel modules?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, compression, kernel-module, lz4

I am using kernel 3.16 and trying to use LZ4 to compress data in memory. I checked kernel source tree, found the compression source file /lib/lz4.c and I used the following function:

```
int lz4_compress(const unsigned char *src, size_t src_len,
            unsigned char *dst, size_t *dst_len, void *wrkmem)
```

But I got the following error:

```
 31.652635] Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: ffffffffc010d13a
[   31.652635] 
[   31.653595] CPU: 0 PID: 1856 Comm: insmod Tainted: P           OE 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[   31.654408] Hardware name: Parallels Software International Inc. Parallels Virtual Platform/Parallels Virtual Platform, BIOS 11.1.3 (32521) 02/16/2016
[   31.655579]  ffff8800aa33e080 ffff8801483d1c90 ffffffff81762590 ffffffff81a75d20
[   31.656295]  ffff8801483d1d08 ffffffff8175aa62 ffff880000000010 ffff8801483d1d18
[   31.657011]  ffff8801483d1cb8 ffffffffc01230ae ffffffffc010d13a 00000000fb25afb4
[   31.657730] Call Trace:
[   31.657966]  [<ffffffff81762590>] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
[   31.658424]  [<ffffffff8175aa62>] panic+0xc8/0x1fc
[   31.658850]  [<ffffffffc01230ae>] ? lz4_compress+0xae/0x1000 [lz4_compress]
[   31.659463]  [<ffffffffc010d13a>] ? hello_init+0x13a/0x140 [test]
[   31.660008]  [<ffffffffc010d000>] ? 0xffffffffc010cfff
[   31.660468]  [<ffffffff8106db2b>] __stack_chk_fail+0x1b/0x20
[   31.660970]  [<ffffffffc010d13a>] hello_init+0x13a/0x140 [test]
[   31.661626] Kernel Offset: 0x0 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[   31.662512] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: ffffffffc010d13a
[   31.662512]
```

My source code:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/lz4.h>

static int hello_init(void){
    unsigned char buf[PAGE_SIZE];
    unsigned char data[PAGE_SIZE];
    int i;
    size_t comp_size;
    unsigned char *dst;
    dst=(unsigned char*)kmalloc(PAGE_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
    memset(dst,0,PAGE_SIZE);
    for(i=0;i<PAGE_SIZE;i++)
        data[i]=i;
    lz4_compress(data, PAGE_SIZE, dst, &comp_size, buf);
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){
    printk("clean up\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

I tried to find some examples about how LZ4 works in kernel modules, but I found nothing. I don't know if anyone has some experience about doing compression in kernel module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The kernel stack size is 2 pages by default. So you initiated stack overflow. If you need example of lz4 using - look into zram, it has lz4 compression backend.
The stack canaries is a special mechanism of protection from buffer overflow attacks (if you are interested in)

Comment: Thanks! I am checking the zram codes recently, I think they are what I need. And about the stack overflow I think you are right. I had these problems before, I will check my codes and see the results, thanks!

Comment: I modified my codes, they are totally work now. Thanks! It was the stack overflow problem, I just modified it to kmalloc. And the functions lz4_compress & lz4_decompress can do the compression work correctly.